# API callouts on Partner Community Licenses

Tags: apex, callout

My company uses Partner community licenses and I was wondering if I can make API callouts using this type of license. I`m asking this because the Partner community license does not have an option to reset 'Security Token' which is required to make callouts. We are integrating Salesforce with a Third Party system and we want users to access their records only. What are my options?

Comment: Hi Wendy, please avoid asking for help (literally typing help in your posts and titles) This way, you minimize amount of text and the issue you are facing is clear. Help will not get you more attention. please take some time to review [ask] .

Comment: @Wendy, just to clarify, do you want to make callouts from Salesforce to the third party system? Or do you want the external system to call into Salesforce with session details from a user with a Partner community license?

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger, I want external system to call into Salesforce with session details from a user with a Partner community license.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found an answer to your question by now?

Based on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickstart_communities.htm) article the OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow does not work for experience cloud. Also is not [recommended](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) anyway as it is not secure.

I am working on the same integration requirements and here are some links that might help you on this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickstart_communities.htm
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_api_access_control_external_users.htm&type=5
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XudcQAC
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

URL to get code: customDomain.sandbox.my.site.com/partners
CustomDomain could be a sandbox one as well.

Hope this helps and please share how you implemented this.